# Script to hide status bar messages in Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

Currently I am using this:

```
OnMouseOver="window.status='';return true;"
```

for:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategory" runat="server" onMouseOver="window.status='' ; return true;" onMouseOut="window.status='';" oncontextmenu="window.status=''; return true;">
```

This works fine in IE but not in Firefox.

How can I be able to change this?

I want to disable the status bar messages for the linkbutton.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the status bar message is **evil**. Don't do it.

Comment: This is not a site for discussing moral issues, that can be easily done at of the tons of social sites out there.

Comment: @TFM - I'm aware of that, but disabling a status bar message is along the lines of covering it up with a horizonal scrolling message marquee intended to cover up where the page links are actually taking the visitor, and should not be humored in any way.

Comment: There are actually legitimate uses of this, not related to hiding links. Like limiting legitimate timed 'web service' calls that IE shows, but no other browsers do. There are known bugs in SignalR that show these messages.

Answer (score 2):

By default, this is [turned off in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status). You'd have to force your users to change a config setting to make this work.

One alternative you could try is swapping out the value `href` with an empty string on hover, then navigating the user to the link's href on click. This is considered a bad thing to do though. It's not bulletproof. Users could still tab to the link or do other things that should trigger a link's default behavior.

As [karim79 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058243/script-to-hide-status-bar-messages-in-firefox-ie-opera-safari/1058265#1058265) though, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling an expected browser behaviour is usually a bad idea. consider if you really need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would caution against this - as others have posted it's expected behaviour.

On a personal note I use the status bar message to check that the link is really going where the page claims. If I found this on a page I'd be highly suspicious of the motives behind the site.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, the user can control what a script is allowed to do. And like it says this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058243/script-to-hide-status-bar-messages-in-firefox-ie-opera-safari/1058267#1058267), the option is turned off by default:

[Firefox settings for javascript http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6683/61224673.jpg](http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/6683/61224673.jpg)

**Edit:** So, there's not much you can do there, as you won't be able to manipulate browser settings with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks like to see messages on their Status Bar. Some don't. Some programmers cover all the bases by including Tool Tips and Status Bar messages in their A tags. Some don't. Some abuse the daylights out of it (eg, scrolling blinkers) which is likely why FF resorted to putting it under User control; where it should be.

Ethical issues aside, don't worry about it. The link text should be clear enough; the additional text in the Tool Tips and Status Bar message should only expand upon that.

For example, if the link text reads 'Home' then the Tool Tip and Status Bar (as you like) should read something like 'Click here to return to Home page.'

The side benefit is that some 'screen readers' for the sight impaired are able to use the additional text in the A tag (although once again everyone seems to have gone their own way on this so, again, covering all the bases seems prudent).

Comment: This is a moral comment. You are not giving an answer to the question, so you should add a comment with you opinion